# Cannot access website deployed on 5gbfree.com

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my website on http://www.5gbfree.com. I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5w7Ik3mTig to deploy my website and done exactly what was told in the video but the problem is whenever I try to hit the URL given to me by 5gbfree (xxxxx.5gbfree.com) it always redirects me to this page.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA9K0.png)

Can somebody help me out and tell me what is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This also took me ages to figure out why.
Try putting https:// infront of your url; `https://xxxxxx.5gbfree.com`.

That seems to work for me, however I get security errors from every browser; from iOS Safari to Mozilla Firefox. I cannot figure that out yet; but keep me updated on fixing that.